# How to Join data from different Excel Files

Tags: c#, .net, excel, join

I have 3 Excel files to manipulate and I want to generate a single Excel file based on them. I need to join the third column of the first file with the first column of the second and third Excel file. What would be the best way to do it in C#.

Comment: don't you want to use SQL server Linked servers? I bet it's fasters solution and it's easy to join tables with this.

Comment: You need to remove "What would be the best library to use" because this falls under category of **off topic: recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**. And your question may be voted to close. Other than that - good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, you may don't have a big project on your hand. If you use `Microsoft.Ace.OleDb` provider to connect to your excel, you will be on your way to success. Check this [To create a new file we simply provide the name of a non existent file in the connection string. This will create a new file.](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2014/07/20/creating-a-new-excel-file-and-adding-data-using-ace/)

So, you can create and read Excel files with provider above. This is thin, nothing like `interop`, and can be safely used on server, like web server.

Since you know how to use your provider [it is literally just like DB], the logic below is - how to join data

1. Read each sheet into a single `DataTable` of a `DataSet`
2. [Create relation between data tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation%28vs.71%29.aspx)
3. Issue joined select
4. Write your resulted row collection into your new Excel file (the link on top explains creation of file and structures in it using provider)

Answer (score 0):

If you work with OpenXML files (.xlsx) you can use the Microsoft OpenXML SDK. It is a library that allows you to open or create .docx, .pptx and .xlsx files:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Otherwise you can automate Excel using C#: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084